# send arrays on redirect via button click

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have the following button:

```
<button class="button" type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='test2.html'">Home</button>
```

Its a simple redirect. My page has a function **getValues()**, **getValues2()** both of which return an array.

a) I want my **Home** button to redirect to the given page and pass in the values from **getValues()**, **getValues2()**

b) I also want to use this passed value in the redirected page so how will I be able to access it? 
Use it in the sense that I want to loop over both the arrays and display them on my html page.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Check `localStorage()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. To persist data you can use SessionStorage. It can only persist JSON values, and it get emptied once a user have closed the browser window. If you don't like this behavior, you can use LocalStorage, which saves data across sessions.

Here's JS:

```
function onRedirect() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("values", JSON.stringify(getValues()));
  sessionStorage.setItem("values2", JSON.stringify(getValues2()));
}

function getValues() {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}

function getValues2() {
  return ["hello", "world"];
}

function renderList(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`).join("");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", onRedirect);

if (window.location.pathname === "/test2.html") {
  const values = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("values"));
  const values2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("values2"));

  document.querySelector(".values").innerHTML = renderList(values);
  document.querySelector(".values2").innerHTML = renderList(values2);
}
```

and here's HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <button class="button" type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='test2.html'">
    Home
  </button>

  <ul class="values">
  </ul>

  <ul class="values2">
  </ul>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/km2o2xv3pr

Comment: Works so far. Is it possible to use these array values in a php code for some backend processing before rendering it on html?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use PHP so can't answer that question

Comment: Can you give any input on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580765/rendering-array-values-in-an-html-table